# Prevent <amp-sidebar> from going back to the top of the page

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to create a simple replacement for my previous hamburger menu, which had some navigation links that would simply scroll pageview to a specified section using `href="#section"`.

Since I cannot use Checkbox trick anymore, I had to use `<amp-sidebar>` for it:

```
<amp-sidebar id="sidebar" layout="nodisplay" side="right">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#secion1">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#secion2">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#secion3">Section 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</amp-sidebar>
```

The problem is, that every time the sidebar is closed, the page gets scrolled back to it's top position (even the URL is reverted to the original state, so the `#section` is removed).

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

That behaviour seems like a bug. Please file an issue on the Github project: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new